# Python - How to plot from precalculated means and confidence intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib

assuming that I already have precalculated means and confidence intervals per year:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["year", "mean", "lower CI", "upper CI"])
df["year"] = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]
df["mean"] = [4.6, 3.9, 3.9, 4.1]
df["lower CI"] = [4.3, 3.7, 3.7, 3.8]
df["upper CI"] = [4.9, 4.2, 4.1, 4.3]
```

How do I plot the custom confidence intervals on a bar chart (i.e. lower CI and upper CI) for each year?

I have this, but it's not working:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
yerror = np.array(df["lower CI"].append(df["upper CI"]))
plt.errorbar(df["year"], df["mean"], yerror=yerror, capsize=5)
```

It's throwing an error, "AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'yerror'"

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lower = df["lower CI"].to_numpy()
upper = df["upper CI"].to_numpy()

yerror = [df["lower CI"].to_numpy(), df["upper CI"].to_numpy()]

plt.errorbar(df["year"], df["mean"], yerr=yerror, capsize=5)
```

Hope this helps someone :)